# Show a SortedList<decimal,KeyValuePair<string,string>> on datagrid wpf

Tags: wpf, datagrid, sortedlist

i have the next list:

```
SortedList<Decimal, KeyValuePair<string,string>> datos;
```

And i need display this in datagrid. But i have one problem. In a sorted list exists KEY and VALUE. This is it.
But as a show within a SortedList KeyValuePair not. I suggest that you can put it in the XAML to specify the key and value into the SortedList KeyValuePair?
My datagrid code is :

```
  <my:WpfDataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" Estilo="StlWpfDataGridAlternatingRows" Estilo_Header="WpfDataGridColumnHeaderAzul" IsReadOnly="False" ItemsSource="{Binding}" Margin="12,12,12,354" Name="dataGridPresentacionPrincipal" SelectionChanged="dataGridPresentacionPrincipal_SelectionChanged">
                <my:WpfDataGrid.Columns>
                    <mic:DataGridTextColumn  Binding="{Binding Key,Mode=OneWay}" Header="Codigo" SortDirection="Ascending" Width="80">
                        <mic:DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                            <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                                <Setter Property="TextAlignment" Value="Right" />
                            </Style>
                        </mic:DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                    </mic:DataGridTextColumn>
                    <mic:DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Value,Mode=OneWay}" Header="Descripcion" SortDirection="Ascending" Width="920" />
                <!--<mic:DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Value,Mode=OneWay}" Header="Producto" SortDirection="Ascending" Width="920" />-->
            </my:WpfDataGrid.Columns>
            </my:WpfDataGrid>
```

On second column, need a key KeyValuePair. And de third column need a value KeyValuePair. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I *think* that you're asking to bind to the child properties of the value (i.e. the KeyValuePair), right? The binding will follow child properties through a dot-notation. Something like

```
<mic:DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Value.Key,Mode=OneWay}" Header="Descripcion" SortDirection="Ascending" Width="920" /> 
<mic:DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Value.Value,Mode=OneWay}" Header="Producto" SortDirection="Ascending" Width="920" />
```

Comment: To selected item from above datagrid :                ((KeyValuePair<decimal, KeyValuePair<string, string>>)(dataGridPresentacionPrincipal.SelectedItem)).Key.ToString();